Error NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER in kafka connect-standalone
I run connect-stanalone.sh with configuration and after change db, Error "NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER" logged in console
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties mongodb-source-connector.properties

Error:
[2024-06-30 03:18:16,919] WARN [mongo-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mongo-source-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 2479 on topic-partition sepas_iums.ehr_extract-0, retrying (2147482409 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:660)
[2024-06-30 03:18:16,919] WARN [mongo-source|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mongo-source-0] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition sepas_iums.ehr_extract-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:686)

mongodb-source-connector.properties
name=mongodb-source-connector
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=sepas_iums
collection=ehr_extract
topic.prefix=mongodb
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000


Are you running multiple brokers?

No just one broker
